# Execute php script daily with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, cron

I found a script that check status of a url. Now i'm trying to integrate it with wordpress. This is the code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: checkOnline Status
Version: 0.1
*/

add_action( 'cO_cron_hook', 'CheckRemoteService' );

if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'cO_cron_hook' ) ) {
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'cO_cron_hook' );
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'bl_deactivate' );

function bl_deactivate() {
$timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'cO_cron_hook' );
wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'cO_cron_hook' );
}

function CheckRemoteService($atts) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
   'url' => 'http://',
   'cache' => '600', // 60*10 (10 minutes)
   'online' => 'Online', // Custom online msg
   'offline' => 'Offline' // Custom online msg
), $atts));

$CachedStatus = 'cstatus_' . $url;
$cachedposts = get_transient($CachedStatus);
if ($cachedposts !== false) {
return $cachedposts;
} else {

// Sometimes its best to change to a custom agent message
// so you know where requests are coming from.

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)";
$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
 curl_exec($ch);
   $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   curl_close($ch);
   if($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 400) {
    return $online;
    } else {
    return $offline;
    }

 set_transient($CachedStatus, $return, $cache); 
return $return;
}
}
add_shortcode('checkmyurl','CheckRemoteService');

?>
```

What i want is run this code only once daily. How can i make it not run when refresh or visit a page where i use shortcodes ? I need display status of about 50 sites and page takes more than 10 sec to load now. 
Sorry for this simple question (i'm a noob to this) but i can't find a solution. 
Thanks.

EDIT. Solved using http://wordpress.org/plugins/crony/

Comment: The name [`cO_**cron**_hook`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is a hint.

Comment: Wordpress cron seems works, function is scheduled. My problem is avoid it loads when enter site and when refresh page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wp_schedule_event()` to schedule recurring tasks.

**`wp_schedule_event()`**([documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)):

> Schedules a hook which will be executed by the WordPress actions core on a specific interval, specified by you. The action will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site, if the scheduled time has passed. See the Plugin API for a list of hooks.

To schedule an event daily, you'd do something like this:

```
function someFunc() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'mydailyEventHook');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This block execution of script if i refresh page ? Thanks.

Comment: When i refresh the page where i use 50 shortcodes to get status of 50 sites , script always runs (taking more than 10 sec). So i need something that block this script to execute when visit that page or refresh it. The user visit page and script runs (more than 10 sec) , user refresh page and script runs again. User should see only results of script from cron. Thanks.