# Create WordPress post from external MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm currently working on a new (WordPress) website that should posts vacancies, from an external database. For testing purpose I have set up a WordPress website that connects with an external database. The connection is no problem and I have also been able to load in tables/rows and display the data (such as title, post-date, content etc..). But I would like each (new) article in my external database to be set up as a new posts in the WordPress website, so these get their own URL/page on the website.

I have set up the DB and displayed some info as below:

```
/* Set-up database */
$servername     =   "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$username       =   "db_user_external";
$password       =   "db_password_external";
$database       =   "db_name_external";

/* Connect to database */
$connectdb      =   mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

/* Query for retrieving data */
$recentposts    =   'SELECT * FROM fposts WHERE posts.post_type = "vacancy" AND posts.post_status = "publish" ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 9';

mysql_select_db($database);

$showvacancy    =   mysql_query( $recentposts, $connectdb );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($showvacancy, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo
    "<p><strong>Vacancy Title:</strong> {$row['post_title']}<br>".
    "<strong>Date published:</strong> {$row['post_date']}<br>".
    "{$row['post_excerpt']}</p>";
}

/* Closing databaseconnection */
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: **Please** stop using the deprecated `mysql_` database library. It was discontinued several years ago due to security issues and removed entirely in PHP7. To protect yourself against likely security vulnerabilities in the library, and also to allow you to use measures such as prepared statements and parameterised queries to defend your data against SQL Injection attacks, I recommend you switch to using the `mysqli_` or `PDO` libraries as soon as possible. Also, if you ever upgrade to PHP7 your code will stop working completely.

Comment: You should use the WP API, not static mysql call to import data in your WordPress install. Include the wp_load.php of the root of the WP install and use the API, like function `wp_insert_post()` to create posts.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first time trying this, so I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup this as a cron job as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600145/execute-php-script-daily-with-wordpress)

Then I would wirte a script that reads the data and then saves that as a post inside a php script as you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605868/how-to-create-a-post-in-wordpress-programmatically).